# SheetJS - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeFile') while calling writeFileAsync method of sheetjs in react js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-excel, sheetjs

I am facing an error in react js application

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeFile')

while calling ***writeFileAsync()*** method of sheetjs in react js application while calling method writeFileAsync.

I have passed filename , workbook object and callback method while calling writeFileAsync method.

Please find the code below.

```
let c= this.generateCDataSheet(geoJSONObj, mappingData);
let e= this.generateEDataSheet(geoJSONObj, mappingData);
let a= this.generateADataSheet(geoJSONObj, mappingData);
let csn= mappingData[DBConstants.cTable.tableName].sheetName;
let esn= mappingData[DBConstants.eTable.tableName].sheetName;
let asn= mappingData[DBConstants.aTable.tableName].sheetName;
utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, c, csn);
utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, e, esn);
utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, a, asn);
let cid= geoJSONObj["properties"]["c"]["parameters"].id;
writeFileAsync(cid+ ".xlsx", workbook, () => {});
```